# Stylus pré-processador - Erro ao rodar o watch do stylus

Tags: javascript, css, preprocessador, stylus, style

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema:

Ao rodar o comando `stylus main.styl main.css -w` o `stylus` compila o que está salvo, ou seja, ele pega o que está nos arquivos `styl/title.styl` e `styl/button.syl` e joga para o arquivo `main.css` em forma de css normal.

Mas quando eu edito e salvo novamente um dos arquivos da pasta `styl` o `stylus` limpa tudo que tem no `main.css` e deixa o arquivo em branco.

E no console fica disparando a mensagem: `compiled main.css` inúmeras vezes.

Meu código:

**main.styl**:

```
@import "styl/*"
```

**styl/title.styl**:

```
h1
    background-color black
    color red
```

**styl/button.styl**:

```
button
    background-color blue
    color red
    width 150px
    height 100px
```

Comment: Testa usar a flag `-o` que especifica que o ficheiro seguinte é o compilado. Assim: `stylus -w main.styl -o main.css`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente cara, valeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa a flag `-o` que especifica que o ficheiro (depois do espaço) é o destino do CSS que será compilado.

Assim: `stylus -w main.styl -o main.css`